# When do you use and access IB objects with viewWithTag instead of via IBOutlet property?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, properties, iboutlet

For every IBOutlet that you need to manage you need to have a pointer, so also need to have a property. Most of the time property needs to be synthesized, then released both in deallloc and viewDidUnload. So actually, there is a little bunch of code that you need to write repeatedly. What you get for that is ease to use and clarity in the code. Now, using and accessing objects from IB with [self.view viewWithTag:] saves a little bit code space but gives a little bit unclarity because you need to remember or to check IB for object tags. So, why does anyone would bother using viewWithTag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, I occasionally need to add buttons dynamically to views, and need to know which one has been pressed, or recall the other buttons.

So that I can do:

```
UIButton *desiredButton = [myView.viewWithTag:theTag]
```

I use to declare the button type (or any view type) in enum so that I can safely assign and recall later:

```
typedef enum {
  ButtonTypeDelete = 1,
  ButtonTypeCancel = 2,
  ButtonTypeAccept = 3,
  ....
  ..
} ButtonType
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many many uses of the tag, also its not necessary to have a outlet for every view element.

1. UITextfields to be filled out in a long form, here tag can be used to auto move the cursor to next field
2. A same IBAction can be connected to multiple button and action can be performed based on tag.

Thinking if i should make this answer a wiki, so that others can contribute to it. Will wait for others to put their answers here.

Comment: point 2 show exactly one of my preferred way of dealing with button actions. I forgot to mention in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You use it everywhere where you won't load the interface from NIBS.
I personally never use interfacebuilder and it is often helpful to not store pointers to all subviews you create (which can be many), but to tag them and identify them using their tags later. Eg I use this technique in the headerview of a UITableView, which I have to change according to user input..